# SharePoint Online shows blank edit form when try to change the Content type from drop down (reqeuirejs)

Tags: sharepoint-online

Following are the steps in sharepoint online:

In documents library using UI I had uploaded a document.

After successfully uploading it shows edit form which allow user to enter meta data:
[image]

When I try to change the content type from the drop down SharePoint throws an exception in require.js :

**Resource ID "82" (provider.bundleLoader) is being consumed, but has not been exposed by a parent scope.**

[image]
[image]

Please let me know what should I do as I am unable to change the CT.
Even when I go to edit properties similar issue arises.

Comment: Is this a custom content type that you are changing to? If so, does it have a parent content type that is also custom?

Comment: It is custom content type and parent content type is document.

Comment: Are you able to add another content type to that document library and recreate the same error? Also, have you tried creating a new document library and attached your custom content type to determine if the issue may reside within your existing document library?

Comment: Its throwing error even for out of the box content type: Document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same issue.  To fix I changed to the Classic Experience in library settings > Advanced Settings > List Experience.

Even though the library was already displayed in the classic experience due to other library settings.